# jQuery AJAX aborted in Laravel 5.2 using jQuery idle timeout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm currently using [jQuery Idle Timeout](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout) in my Laravel 5.2 system.
It is working fine in my local computer (MAMP Pro) but when I uploaded it to the development server then the AJAX get request gives an "**Aborted**" error:
[image: jQuery AJAX request Aborted error in Laravel 5.2]

What seems to be the problem?

**Laravel Routes Code:**

```
Route::get('/keepalive', function () {
    return view('keepalive');
});
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
// dialog is in the main layout after login = admin.blade.php
$("#dialog_session_timeout").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Yes, Keep Working': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'No, Logoff': function() {
            // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
            // using .call(this) keeps the default behavior of "this" being the warning
            // element (the dialog in this case) inside the callback.
            $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
        }
    }
});
// cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");
var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
var data = {
    '_token': _token
};
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

// start the idle timer plugin
$.idleTimeout('#dialog_session_timeout', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    //idleAfter: 5, // in seconds
    idleAfter: 7170, // 2 hours minus 30 seconds. 2 hours in the config/sessions.php
    pollingInterval: 10,
    //keepAliveURL: base_url + '/keepalive.php',
    keepAliveURL: base_url + '/keepalive',
    data: data,
    serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
    onTimeout: function() {
        window.location = "logout";
    },
    onIdle: function() {
        $(this).dialog("open");
    },
    onCountdown: function(counter) {
        $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the value of`base_url`?

Comment: @srph An IP Address with port 8080 like 123.456.789.222:8080

Comment: Can you try setting `AJAXTimeout` to at least `1000`? I know it sounds stupid because `AJAXTimeout` is `250` by default (while your requests are under `250`). But let's just try :)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this type of problem, which is working fine locally but not on production server.
The error is throwing because of Ajax option

> timeout

The default AJAXTimeout option in jquery-idletimeout plugin is 250 (ms) which is sometime low for requesting. You need either to explicitly define the "AJAXTimeout" option in idletimeout initialization, like:

```
// start the idle timer plugin
$.idleTimeout('#dialog_session_timeout', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: 7170, // 2 hours minus 30 seconds. 2 hours in the config/sessions.php
    AJAXTimeout: 2000,  // instead of 250 ms
    pollingInterval: 10,
    keepAliveURL: base_url + '/keepalive',
    //data: data,      // no option like this exist in idletimeout plugin
    serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
    onTimeout: function() {
       window.location = "logout";
    },
    onIdle: function() {
       $(this).dialog("open");
    },
    onCountdown: function(counter) {
       $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
    }
});
```

or go to "jquery.idletimeout.js" file and comment the timeout option in ajax request, like below:

```
$.ajax({
    //timeout: options.AJAXTimeout,
    url: options.keepAliveURL,
    error: function(){
        self.failedRequests--;
    },
    success: function(response){
        if($.trim(response) !== options.serverResponseEquals){
            self.failedRequests--;
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        if( recurse ){
            self._startTimer();
        }
    }
});
```

NOTE: you can't set "data" attribute in idletimeout options instead you can set it in the ajax request which is exist in jquery.idletimeout.js file but you don't need to set that option actually. :)